# Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed referencing another worksheet

Tags: vba

Here is my Code:

```
Sub showUnique()

Dim VAriable As String
Dim irange As Range
Dim car As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim inew As Range

Set Source = ActiveSheet

Range("f2").Activate 'starting point

Do
    If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        VAriable = ActiveCell.Value
        Set irange = Range("f1:f1000")
    car = -Application.CountIf(irange, VAriable) + 1
  Set inew = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(car, 0)).EntireRow

'inew.Select

Set Target = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.count)) ' after last sheet
Target.Name = VAriable
' 'header row
Source.Range("a1:h1").Copy Target.Range("a1")
'handle Vehicle sales
' Set Target = Worksheets.Add(after:=Source) 'after active shett

' 'copy data
Source.Range(inew).Copy Target.Range("a2")
Target.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
writeKPI
    End If
    Sheets("Sales").Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

End Sub
```

Getting the error "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" on the line of code

```
Source.Range(inew).Copy Target.Range("a2")
```

I am trying to reference a range on a different worksheet and copy that data to a new worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Your `inew` variable is a `Range`, so you should just use

```
inew.Copy Target.Range("a2")
```

---

You should, however, go through your code and:

- get rid of the `Activate`s (see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/6535336)),
- fully qualify your references to `Range`s.  For example, I think

  ```
  Set inew = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(car, 0)).EntireRow
  ```

  is probably meant to be

  ```
  Set inew = Sheets("Sales").Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(car, 0)).EntireRow
  ```